# Authentication with Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis

I'm trying to better understand Redis Sentinel authentication.
Would appreciate it if someone could clarify.

Per Redis Sentinel documentation,

```
You can also configure the Sentinel instance itself in order to require
client authentication via the AUTH command, however this feature is only
available starting with Redis 5.0.1.
In order to do so, just add the following configuration directive to all
your Sentinel instances: requirepass <your_password_here?
```

My questions:

1. Does Redis Sentinel password have to be identical to that of the master?
2. Would password-protected Sentinel nodes work with master that does not require authentication? I realize that this scenario might not make much sense, but I'm just wondering if this use case is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some informations on this [link](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#sentinel-and-redis-authentication)